# Attempted to assign to readonly property in React Native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following (simplified) class:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            result: null,
        }

        // Input values
        this.wg = null;

        // Reset error flags
        this.resetErrors();
    }

    resetErrors() {
        this.wg_error = false;
    }


    inputErrorFound() {
        return this.wg_error;
    }

    calculate() {
        // Check input values
        if (this.wg == null) {
            this.wg_error = true;
        }

        if (this.inputErrorFound()) {
            alert("Do something here");
        } else {
            //More stuff..
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an "Attempted to assign to readonly property" error on the line with `this.wg_error = true;`. Can someone explain why this is, and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Any particular reason `wg` and `wg_error` is not part of your `state`?

Comment: Because I don't want to update the UI based on these. But this could be a conceptual mistake on my part.

Comment: Can you make a working example on somewhere like Stackbltiz.com?

Comment: I doubt `this.wg_error = true;` this line get execute, coz when `this.wg = 0;` then `if (this.wg == null) {` never be true. Do you have any other code snippet which sets `this.wg == null`?

Comment: @zmag Seems to work there https://react-h1yocx.stackblitz.io

Comment: @ravibagul91Sorry, that was a pasting error. Updated to show the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Hate when this happens. Even though it's a basic mistake, I'll leave it:

Was (not in snippet):

```
<Button label="Calculate" onClick={ this.calculate } />
```

Should be:

```
<Button label="Calculate" onClick={ () => this.calculate() } />
```